# SimpleInjector lazy generic registration

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I am working with some old asp.net web form pages and trying to get the DI to work but running into an issue with some objects not being created so am aiming to do a lazy implementation in the code behind.

I have the following registration working in the rest of the website:

```
container.Register(typeof(IDataFactory<,>), new[] { typeof(SqlAccountFactory).Assembly });
```

To get the lazy aspect I have tried

```
container.Register<Lazy<IDataFactory<SqlAccountFactory, int>>>(
            () => new Lazy<IDataFactory<SqlAccountFactory, int>>(
                container.GetInstance<IDataFactory<SqlAccountFactory, int>>));
```

The outcome of this is that the property does not get populated.

Property in code behind of page (as described above this works when not using Lazy):

```
[Dependency]
public Lazy<IDataFactory<SqlAccountFactory, int>> ProjectCodesRepository;
```

For reference I am using the code from the documentation to populate the properties in code behinds marked with attributes and all works well bar the above lazy registration.

Is anybody able to help or spot something silly I have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Injector's `IPropertySelectionBehavior` only works on properties. What you defined however is a public field, not a property. If you change it to the following, it will probably start working:

```
[Dependency]
public Lazy<IDataFactory<SqlAccountFactory, int>> ProjectCodesRepository { get; set; }
```

It is wise to mark your `DependencyAttribute` in such way that it only supports properties, by marking it with an `AttributeUsageAttribute` as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class DependencyAttribute : Attribute { }
```

This ensures that the C# compiler will show a compile error in case you put the attribute on a field.

Long story short, it has nothing to do with the dependency being lazy.

Comment: Solved my issue, I mangled the property trying to fix the registration. Adding the AttributeUsage will prevent it in the future; thanks!

Comment: Do note though that it is generally a bad idea for dependencies to be a `Lazy<T>`. The creation of objects sjould be really fast since ctors should do nothing more than storing their dependencies.